# The use of parameter c and cmap in python matplotlib

Tags: python

When plotting random walk with colormap using scatter(), the following code is from the book <> where `c=point_numbers`, i.e. range(0,5000), but I tried `c=rw.x_values`, which also works fine. Is there any specific rule of assigning ‘c’?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk

while True:
    rw=RandomWalk()
    rw.fill_walk()
    point_numbers=list(range(rw.num_points))
    plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, c=point_numbers,
        cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolor = 'none', s=15)
    plt.show()
    keep_running = input("Make another walk?(y/n): ")
    if keep_running == 'n':
        break
```

note that `point_numbers` is a list with 5000 integers sorted by 0 to 5000, `rw.x_values` is also a list with 5000 random integers.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Comment: "cmap is only used if c is an array of floats", but both point_numbers and rw.x_values conform to it, why use point_numbers?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The documentation is a bit misleading here, since `cmap` will be used if `c` is either an array of floats or integers (integers will be mapped to floats in the 0-1 range before applying `cmap` anyway. `cmap` is not used in other cases (i.e. if `c` is a 2D array, an array of colors, or it is a single color.

In any case though, in order to use `cmap` you need an array of numbers. `rw.num_points` is a single number, not an array.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, `rw.num_points=5000` so it is not a single number, `x_values` and `y_values` are lists with 5000 random numbers, as well. So i'm quite confusing the difference between using them.

Comment: 5000 is a single number. An array is a sequence of numbers.  For example, `point_numbers` is such a sequence consisting of 5000 integers - staring from 0 and ending at 4999.

Comment: oh no, `point_numbers` is a list, you can see on the code, it is `point_numbers=list(range(rw.num_points))`

Comment: Sure, this is what I wrote. `point_numbers` is a list, and `rw.num_points` is a single integer. You cannot use `cmap` with a single integer, but you can with a list.

Comment: yes, I think I know that, but in my original question, `c=rw.x_values` also works fine because `x_values` is also a list with 5000 random numbers, so why the book assign a new list to `c` instead of simply using `rw.x_values`?

Comment: Sorry, I understand the issue now. The values of the array assigned to `c` determine which color gets assigned to each plotted point. With `cmap=plt.cm.Blues` bigger values will give darker blue colors. If you use `c=point_numbers` the points will be getting darker as their indices will be growing, since values of `point_numbers` are increasing. On the other hand, if you set `c=rw.x_values`, then darker points will be the ones with larger x-coordinates (since `rw.x_values` gives x-coordinates of points). So colors will be getting darker moving from the left-hand side of the plot to the right.

Comment: Oh I see, yes I just tried, exactly like you said! That's great, thank you so much!